# PHP/MySQL - Friends List SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, database, list

I'm going based off this guide in a previous StackOverflow post:

```
"Table Name: User
Columns:
    UserID PK
    EmailAddress
    Password
    Gender
    DOB
    Location

TableName: Friends
Columns:
    UserID PK FK
    FriendID PK FK
    (This table features a composite primary key made up of the two foreign 
     keys, both pointing back to the user table. One ID will point to the
     logged in user, the other ID will point to the individual friend
     of that user)

Example Usage:

Table User
--------------
UserID EmailAddress Password Gender DOB      Location
------------------------------------------------------
1      bob@bob.com  bobbie   M      1/1/2009 New York City
2      jon@jon.com  jonathan M      2/2/2008 Los Angeles
3      joe@joe.com  joseph   M      1/2/2007 Pittsburgh

Table Friends
---------------
UserID FriendID
----------------
1      2
1      3
2      3"
```

Now, I have all that done, and I've created this query:

```
if ($_SESSION["user_id"]) {
    $user_id = $_SESSION["user_id"];
    $query = "SELECT * ";
    $query .= "FROM friends ";
    $query .= "WHERE ";
    $query .= "user_id OR friend_id = '{$user_id}' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    $result_set = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    print_r($result_set);
```

Yay! This print_r gets the associated array that I expected.
But now, because either user_id OR friend_id can be the logged in user, I'm stumped s to what kind of query I need to go with to be able to actually display the friends list.

```
$query = "SELECT * ";
$query .= "FROM users ";
$query .= "WHERE id = ''
```

This is about as far as I've gotten due to my confusion.
Any point in the right direction would be amazing. thank you!

Comment: Aside from not having your `$user_id` value, what is wrong with the second query you wrote? What is returned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh I get it. You (the user) want to display your friends (other users)

Try this:

```
SELECT U.EmailAddress, U.Gender, U.DOB, U.Location FROM User U
LEFT JOIN Friends F on U.UserID = F.Friend_ID WHERE F.User_ID = 1;
```

And then just change 1 to whatever the logged in user's id is.

Cheers!

Comment: thank you tim! ive never used that "u." format before. when you put "FROM User U" , should your "User" actually be the name of my table, which is "users" with a lower case u, or is the capital required?

edit: oh, im sorry. In the example the tables are actually named that. It's mine that are named differently. thank you very much, i understand it!

Comment: tim, do you think theres anyway to could break down in english what this MySQL query is performing for me exactly? i have it where it is not producing any errors, but i still cant print_r($result_set) on this query once it is completed. edit: IT WORKS. I GOT IT WORKING. thank you so much tim :)

Comment: Hey man no problem. What this MySQL query is doing is Selecting Email Address, Gender, Date of Birth and Location from all users, then joining the Friends table (using the column Friends.Friend_ID = Users.UserID) then showing only the results where Friends.User_ID = The selected ID. This was a bit more of a complex join, but I'm glad you got it working :)

Answer (score 0):

**PHP**

```
$reg_no = $_SESSION["user_id"];
```

**SQL QUERY:**

```
select * from `User` join `friends` on '$reg_no' = `friends`.`UserID` and `User`.`UserID` = `friends`.`UserID` or '$reg_no' = `FriendID` and `User`.`UserID` = `friends`.`UserID`;
```

TRY IT ....